# really stupid newbee question about antd select for react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do a my first react act and I can't get the antd select to work.  I am trying to just do one of the selects from the example on the page. It looks like the code below and I can't get the select to look or work properly.  I click on jack and nothing happens

[image]

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the `const { Option } = Select ` all about? Remove that and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like your replicating [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/33rue)

Comment: Yeah.  That's the thing.  It doesn't work and I'm replicating the example.  I feel like a huge idiot.  The option thing allows you without error in typescript to add the drop down options to the select.  I am pretty sure I tried opening it in Firefox and  Chrome

Comment: It really was my stupidity.   

You need the css sheet. I forgot to iimport the css sheet

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css'`

if you are using react-bootscript you also need to import the default css